# Post request does not working with Spring security and angular 5

Tags: spring, angular, rest, spring-security, cors

In my application we are using, apache wicket, Angular 5 and Spring-REST,
we have different technologies for UI wicket and angular and spring rest all are deployed in same server.

In application using spring security for authorization, when angular GET request coming to server it works fine, but when POST request come CORS filter wont respond to angular getting error 403.

we configured CORS filter below

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,x-requested-with");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "48000");
```

Comment: Can you provide a dump of the failed post inclusive http error Message

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have to send the bearer with your requests. If you don't, then yes, you get a 403 (Unauthorized) response.

Add an `Authorization` header to your requests containing `Bearer [token]`.

And if you did and still not works, consider exposing the headers from your back-end. In your CORS configuration, configure the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header to expose the `Authorization` header.